# NoMethodError: undefined method '-@'

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-2.0

Here is my Sinatra code

```
  def self.sort_by_date_or_price(items, sort_by, sort_direction)
    if sort_by == :price
      items.sort_by{|x| sort_direction == :asc ? x.item.current_price : -x.item.current_price}
    elsif sort_by == :date
      items.sort_by{|x| sort_direction == :asc ? x.created_date : -x.created_date}
    end
  end
```

when I call this method as #`sort_by_date_or_price(items, :date, :desc)` it returns the error of   `NoMethodError: undefined method '-@' for 2013-02-05 02:43:48 +0200:Time`

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to write a unary operator `-` method for that. This is not present,thus getting the error I am sure  from the line `-x.item.current_price` or `-x.created_date`.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu, this code works `items.sort_by{|x|-x.created_date}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `unary -` operator in not defined in the class [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html) used by `created_date`. You should convert it to an integer :

```
items.sort_by{|x| sort_direction == :asc ? x.created_date.to_i : -x.created_date.to_i}
```

That could also be written

```
items.sort_by{|x| x.created_date.to_i * (sort_direction == :asc ? 1 : -1)}
```

Comment: I'd simply do a `reverse` at the end if `sort_direction != :asc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person
end
#=> nil
ram = Person.new()
#=> #<Person:0x2103888>
-ram
NoMethodError: undefined method `-@' for #<Person:0x2103888>
        from (irb):4
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Now see how I fixed it below:

```
class Person
  def -@
   p "-#{self}"
  end
end
#=> nil
ram = Person.new()
#=> #<Person:0x1f46628>
-ram
#=>"-#<Person:0x1f46628>"
=> "-#<Person:0x1f46628>"
```

Comment: @AlanDert The error you mentioned comes only when my post mentioned scenario comes into situation. Try to see what I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @AlanDert you have to write a method for the unary operator `-`. in the class. This kind of error only comes when there is no method for unary operators `-`,`+` etc. In such a case you need to write the method if you want your object should respond on that call `-ram`.